# UISearchController setActive does nothing

Tags: swift, uisearchcontroller

I'm trying to present a search controller in response to a button, by setting its `isActive` property, but it doesn't appear.

```
lazy var searchController: UISeachController = {
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.delegate = self
    return searchController
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    definesPresentationContext = true
}

// Called when a button on the navbar is tapped
@obcj private func searchTapped() {
    // The doc says you can force the search controller to appear by setting isActive,
    // but nothing happens
    searchController.isActive = true

    // Calling present does show it, but the search bar appears behind the navbar. 
    // And the delegate methods are still not called
    //present(searchController, animated: true)
}

func willPresentSearchController(_ searchController: UISearchController) {
    // Not called, even when calling 'present'
}
```

Comment: You have no search results controller and no search bar, so exactly what are you expecting will happen?

Comment: The search controller configures its search bar automatically, and the search results controller is optional. I'm using a table view controller for the results, but that is not relevant to my question. The search controller presents correctly when calling present explicitly, so I don't think there's anything missing.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems `isActive` only works if the search bar is in the view hierarchy.

```
// This will place the search bar in the title view, allowing you to
// have other buttons on the right of the search bar.
navigationItem.titleView = searchController.searchBar
```

Or

```
// This takes up a whole other row under title row.
navigationItem.searchController = searchController
```

But if you go this route, you don't need to set isActive yourself - the search controller automatically comes up when the user interacts with the search bar. I still don't understand how isActive is supposed to be used, but it does answer the original question.

Comment: Yup but that was my original point. No new news here.

Comment: If the question is, is there a use case for isActive, yes there is.

Comment: Well, sorry I was so shy. When I said "You have no search results controller and no search bar", I meant, "This thing is meaningless without a search bar in the interface (and possibly without a search results controller)." I was trying to give you a hint.